# Gradle 'demo' project refresh failed: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to use new gradle android build system on my multiproject. I've library project and demo project that depends on it. I've problems with dependencies block.

```
Gradle 'demo' project refresh failed:
        Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle installation '/Users/lia/Worktable/gradle/tools/external/gradle/gradle-1.6'.
        Build file '/Users/lia/Worktable/screen-tester-android/demo/build.gradle' line: 43
        A problem occurred evaluating project ':demo'.
        A problem occurred evaluating project ':demo'.
        No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated) values: [project ':screentester']
        Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)
```

Using gradle 1.6

Settings.gradle

```
include ':demo', ':screentester'
```

demo build.gradle dependencies block

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    compile project(':screentester')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that dependencies block in buildscript? I think you are mixing the classpath of the build and the dependencies of your project. It should look something like:

```
// this is to configure the code running the build, ie where to find the plugin
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}

// now we configure the project itself
dependencies {
  compile project(':screentester')
}
```